# How to reject sign-up trigger with GoLang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I've successfully created a lambda function using Go for the pre sign-up trigger of AWS Cognito.
My problem is that I'm not being able to deny/reject the user if a custom field is not valid (based on custom logic).

I'm returning an error as described in AWS Cognito trigger's guide:

```
return event, fmt.Errorf("Invalid value for field 'custom:myField'")
```

also I've tried this options:

- returning an empty event (nil is not allowed for the event):

  ```
  var emptyEvent events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup
  return emptyEvent, fmt.Errorf("Invalid value for field 'custom:myField'")
  ```
- changing ValidationData in the original event:

  ```
  event.Request.ValidationData = map[string]string{"custom:myField": "Invalid value for field 'custom:myField."}
  return event, fmt.Errorf("Invalid value for field 'custom:myField'")
  ```
- changing UserAttributes in the original event

  ```
  event.Request.UserAttributes["email"] = ""
  return event, fmt.Errorf("Invalid value for field 'custom:myField'")
  ```

All those methods are failing, the user is always created in the User Pool.

What should be the correct way to reject the sign-up request using GoLang lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something changed on AWS Cognito Lambda triggers, since today I tried the following source code and it worked as expected:

```
func handler(event events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup) (events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup, error) {
    fmt.Println(event)
    return event, fmt.Errorf("TESTING LAMBDA ERRORS WITH GOLANG")
}
```

Also, the previous source code that was not working as expected when I posted this question is currently working (with no changes on my side).